# libpcap - capture packets from all interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, network-protocols, pcap, libpcap

I need to capture packets from all network interfaces on Linux machine.
In order to do it I'm planning to use `pcap_open_live()` API and pass "any" as a device argument.

I have different types of ports: Ethernet ports (say eth0) and GRE tunnels (say tun0) 
The packets that coming from different types of interfaces has different headers format:

1. Packets from Ethernet port has MAC header
2. Packets from tunnel coming with a Linux "cooked" capture encapsulation (16 bytes) header

How can I check into `pcap_loop()` callback handler what type of packet header I got?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All packets you receive get the same type of packet header; that's the type you get when you call `pcap_datalink()` on the pcap_t.  The values that `pcap_datalink()` returns are the `DLT_` values as shown in the [Link-Layer Header Types](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) page on the tcpdump.org site.

If you've opened the `any` device, `pcap_datalink()` will return `DLT_LINUX_SLL`, meaning that *ALL* packets you capture will have the "cooked" capture header - even the ones from `eth0`!  You'd have to capture on `eth0`, rather than `any`, to get Ethernet headers for those packets.