# Can't get protocol while capture any interfaces with libpcap

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, libpcap, packet-sniffers

I using `libpcap` code to capture network traffic in my Ubuntu with the following code I have problem the parse the protocol of packet:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *device = "any";
    char error_buffer[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t *handle;
    const u_char *packet;
    struct pcap_pkthdr packet_header;
    int packet_count_limit = 1;
    int timeout_limit = 20000; /* In milliseconds */
    bpf_u_int32 net;
    bpf_u_int32 mask;

    if ( -1 == pcap_lookupnet(device ,&net,&mask,error_buffer))
    printf("error netmask\n");


    /* Open device for live capture */
    handle = pcap_open_live(
            device ,
            BUFSIZ,
            packet_count_limit,
            timeout_limit,
            error_buffer
        );
    if(NULL == handle)
        printf("error! %s\n",error_buffer);
    struct pcap_pkthdr* header;
    u_char *buffer;

    while(1)
    {
    
        int ret  = pcap_next_ex(handle,&header, &buffer);
    if(header->len ==0)
    {
        printf("cont\n");
        continue;

    }

    struct  iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*) (buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    printf("protocol = %d \n", iph->protocol);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is , when I choose to capture in `any` interfaces `char *device = "any";`  I always get **protocol = 0**

But when I choose `char *device = "ens33";` I got right protocol (like 6 for TCP)

why is that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [libpcap - capture packets from all interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995741/libpcap-capture-packets-from-all-interfaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libpcap will sometimes, depending upon the interface chosen, replace the layer 2 header (ethernet, in this case) with a [Linux cooked header](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SLL) which does not have the same length as an ethernet header.  You can check the datalink type of your `pcap_t` with the `pcap_datalink` function.

```
unsigned int layer_2_header_length;

switch ( pcap_datalink(handle) ) {
case DLT_EN10MB: // Ethernet header
    layer_2_header_length = 14;
    break;

case DLT_LINUX_SLL: // Linux cooked header
    layer_2_header_length = 16;
    break;

// other options
}
```

Comment: That work but I didn't understand why it's work , 1) should I calculate  `layer_2_header_length ` each packet received  (in the while) or only before the while ?   2) why does it changed between `ens33` and `any` ? thanks!

Comment: Once you set up a `pcap_t`, the layer 2 header size will be the same for every packet captured.  The reason why it changes between "ens33" and "any" is because, when you're capturing on all interfaces, you could have multiple layer 2 types coming in.  Therefore, they need to be standardized.

Comment: "Once you set up a `pcap_t,` the layer 2 header size will be the same for every packet captured."  Not for all layer 2 types; IEEE 802.11, for example, has a variable-length layer 2 header.

Comment: Huh.  I did not know that.  Thanks!

Comment: is there more option than `DLT_LINUX_SLL`  `DLT_EN10MB` ?

Comment: There are.  You should read the documentation for details.

Comment: See also [the tcpdump.org link-layer header types page](https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html).